# Create variable laravel

Tags: laravel

i need to create one variable of text in LARAVEL

```
if((strlen($tpesquisa ))<4) {
    return view('pesquisa');
    ///////// for example msgm= 'it is necessary to use more than 4 words to start searching';
}

/////////////// for example msgm= 'were found x results';

return view('pesquisa',compact('produtos'));
```

and in view print the msgm
`<p>{{$msgm}}</p>`
how create the variable with value text?
and how can I measure the results?

Comment: `$msgm = 'whatever'; return view('pesquisa',compact('produtos', 'msgm'));`

Comment: can you tell me how can i count the results?

Comment: @MicaG you should have a look at the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just define

`$msgm = 'whatever the text'`

And then, in the return view you can do:

`return view('pesquisa',compact('produtos', 'msgm'));`